# The script which runs python in shell

Tags: python, linux, shell

I am running python on Linux.
I want to know the script which runs the python interpreter.

Meaning, Whenever i run the command `python` on a linux shell, a Python prompts opens and get input from keyboard and take those inputs to the underlying python interpreter.I want to know which shellscript (or python script) does this?. I want to know the location of it.

Comment: `which python` is the standard unix way to do this. Of course, there is no reason to assume it will be a script.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a python script you can simply get and modify as any .py file. In order to play around with interactive interpretter you will have to download the python sources and go through them, as it's a build-in part of it (for performance sake).

You can read up the details on http://docs.python.org/devguide/

Comment: could you be more specific on where to find the sources pertaining to the 'Interactive interpreter'

Comment: The given URL shows you how to get the C source code of the python interpreter. You can also try http://python.org/download/

Comment: I am not sure what do you consider as "interactive interpreter", but if you are after the I/O part then here you go http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/00695551d721/Modules/main.c

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question as asked is **None**!

The Linux default python prompt is part of the python interpreter and is a *binary* file **not** a python script or shell script.  The path to the binary can be found by the Linux command:

```
which python
```